# "sh: 1: ./binary: Permission denied" on Elastic Container Service

Tags: docker, dockerfile, amazon-ecs

Can't figure this out at all. My Dockerfile works fine locally and on an EC2 Linux server but on ECS using Fargate it always gets the error shown in title when trying to run my binary.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

WORKDIR /usr/app

# install TLS certificates
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install ca-certificates -y

# copy binary file
COPY ./binary ./binary

# run executable on start
ENTRYPOINT chmod +x ./binary && ./binary
```

Tried a very wide combination of things, messing with the container definition settings (entry point, command etc) but still the same error every time. Was wondering if anyone has experienced this and how you fixed it, or if anyone could provide an example Dockerfile that works on ECS.

If it matters, the binary in question is a Go binary, built for Linux (amd64).

Comment: Pls provide your ECS task definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out ECS was making a directory by itself somehow, was definitely not my Dockerfile. Replacing my `ENTRYPOINT` with `CMD ["/bin/bash", "-c", "chmod +x /usr/app/binary/binary && /usr/app/binary/binary"]` fixed the issue (`/usr/app` being the working directory.)